# Tasker svn commands to create tag from trunk

Tags: android, svn, tags, command, tasker

How can i use a tasker to execute svn command?

i want to create a svn tag from trunk. ex:

> svn copy http ://ipserver:port/project/files/trunk \ 
>   http ://ipserver:port/project/files/tags/1.0 -m "My Release 1.0"

How can I do this on tasker android?

PS: I have to login on svn server before that tag.

Comment: Do you have a Subversion client on your device?

Comment: no i haven't. i install oasVN but i think for this commands i need will not work